# Why can't we learn what we are not interested in?

Tags: psychology, education

The school system, as we know it, is and has been shaping students to fit the system in which they live. Throughout this process, the students are forced to *learn* (mostly memorize) subjects in which they do not have any interest whatsoever and because of this they can't score high in school. It is as if our brains are trying to avoid information, which is not interesting as much as possible. But when there is something of interest it is very easy to collect and comprehend that information.

Let's assume that you are a programmer and you are greatly amazed by that. You love solving problems and developing software. You read lots of documentation and contribute on other people's projects without even having to worry about "remembering" what you're reading. Everything is easily understood and there's no issue with that. But when you have to learn about politics and how the system works, it appears as a cancer to your eyes because you have no interest in it. There's no *will* to collect that information and therefore you score low in that subject.

Now my question is: **Why can't we learn what we don't like? Why can't we learn what we're not interested in?**

Comment: This seems like a question for psychology, not philosophy.

Comment: I made some edits which you may roll back or continue editing. I agree with Eliran H that this probably would get better answers from the psychology and neuroscience SE: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/?newreg=2310163eca5f4977b21cdebaa9858c97 Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Comment: It's not that we can't, it is that we *choose* not to.

Comment: @Bread Then why can't we choose to? In either way, the question is not within the scope of philosophy. Except if we'll end up discussing free will.

Comment: @rus9384 Some people do choose to, so it is a question of free will.

Comment: @Bread I am not sure it can be a productive discussion. They choose, they already are interested in. The question is about those who are not interested in.

Comment: Some people are hunters, some are farmers. A farmer can learn to hunt, but he’d rather be filling the fields. We all have propensities that drive interest

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is not exactly correct, we CAN learn something that we are not interested in, we passively learn a lot of things that we are not even aware of let alone interested in.

No learning is impossible though, while it may seem "hard" for you to learn something you're not very interested in, there are ways of making it more interesting, but even without those with some effort no matter what you WILL learn it, being interested in a matter merely makes it easier to remember and learn but interest is by no means a requirement for learning.

Comment: At least this answer shows that the question is based on a false premise.